# Vector Spaces - Find the basis and dimension of the space

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the problem with this one. Find the basis and dimension of the space $V=\{(-2x-y-4z,x-3y-5z,3x+y+5z) : x,y,z ∈ R\}$ Find the coordinates of the vector v=(-5,-1,7) in this base. I determined $V=lin\{(-2,1,3),(-1,-3,1),(-4,-5,5)\}$ but I have a problem because these vectors are linearly dependent, that's the moment where I get stuck. How to determine basis of this space?

Comment: It is **a** basis rather than **the** basis. If a, b, and c span the space but are linearly dependent and, as an example, c = a + b, then just a and b span the space. If they are linearly independent then a and b make up a basis.

Comment: @Peter so the vector v=(-5,-1,7) in this basis will have 2 coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

You're right:  the vectors are dependent.   The third equals the first plus twice the second.

The first two, $\{(-2,1,3),(-1,-3,1\}\}$ form a basis (they're independent).

So the space has dimension $2$, and everything can be expressed as a $2$-tuple.

We have $(-5,-1,7)=2\cdot(-2,1,3)+1\cdot (-1,-3,1).$  So the coordinates are $(2,1).$

You actually get the following system of $3$ equations in $2$ unknowns:  $$\begin {pmatrix}-2\quad-1\\1\quad-3\\3\quad 1\end {pmatrix}\begin {pmatrix}x\\y\end {pmatrix}=\begin {pmatrix}-5\\-1\\7\end {pmatrix}.$$